# changing img src through jQuery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change my img src with jQuery click function but can't seem to do it. Here is my html code:

```
<div id="main2"><img id='mty' style="width: 500px;height: 600px;"
src="https://cdn.pastemagazine.com/www/articles/morty%20main.jpg">
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code that won't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#paper').click(function() 
{
$('#mty').attr('src', 'http://www.cliparthut.com/clip-arts/1008/paper-stack-clip-art-1008442.jpg');
});  </script>
```

what am I doing wrong? I want to be able to change the html src if I click on #paper which is a button btw.

Comment: Where is element with id paper. Can you please add button tag also in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#mty').attr('src', 'http://www.cliparthut.com/clip-arts/1008/paper-stack-clip-art-1008442.jpg');
```

You need to set "src" to img tag, not the div tag

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $('#paper').click(function() { 
           $('#mty').attr('src', 'http://www.cliparthut.com/clip-arts/1008/paper-stack-clip-art-1008442.jpg'); 
       }); 
   }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Add your click event within document.ready..  

       $(document).ready(function(){ //add click listener here });

Comment: try this script;
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#paper').click(function() { 
                  $('#mty').attr('src', 'http://www.cliparthut.com/clip-arts/1008/paper-stack-clip-art-1008442.jpg');
          });
     });  
</script>

Comment: Where is element with id paper, which is used as click?

Comment: Such mistake happens in Javascript. Glad you made it.

Comment: one type took so long for me to find

Answer (score 0):

Html is as-

```
<button type="button" id="paper">change image</button>
<div id="main2">
    <img id='mty' style="width: 500px;height: 600px;"
         src="https://cdn.pastemagazine.com/www/articles/morty%20main.jpg">
</div>
```

Script-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#paper').click(function () {
        $('#mty').attr('src', 'http://www.cliparthut.com/clip-arts/1008/paper-stack-clip-art-1008442.jpg');
    });
</script>
```

Things to remember-

> User script after html render or use jquery ready.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="random image"/>
   <button id="changeImage">Change image</button>
   <script>
     $('#changeImage').on('click', function(){
    
    $('#image').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200');
     });
   </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation as to what the OP (original poster) did wrong. Other than that, nice answer. I like that you've added in the ability to run the code snippet.

Comment: Thanks, Original poster not post details code. That's why I put details.